# Add objects to listbox

Tags: gwt

I am looking for a way to add objects other than just strings to a listbox.

For Example if i have an object of type Car with the fields brand,cost,colour, I want to be able to select the car in the listbox which displays the brand and use a changehandler to display the cost in a window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [`CellList`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellList.html). Here's an [example](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) of what it can look like.

What you'll need to do is create your own type of [`Cell`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/cell/client/Cell.html) for which you supply it the object you want to display and it takes care of creating the HTML to display it.

You'll need to then put your values in a list and possibly a [`ListDataProvider`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/view/client/ListDataProvider.html) which will give the `CellList` the objects it needs.

The [`CellList`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellList.html) javadoc has a few good basic examples for all this.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.